# Accessing an element inside a UserControl resource

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a xaml file where I defined a `UserControl` with a `storyboard` as a resource this way:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateImage">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="RotateImageAnimation" From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"/>
        </Storyboard>            
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I'd like to access the RotateImageAnimation from the code behind, but if I write something like:

```
public void Foo(){
    RotateImageAnimation.To = 170;
}
```

I get a runtime `NullPointerException`. How can I access the element within the resource? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access your resources using the following code:

```
public void Foo(){
    var storyBoard = this.Resources["RotateImage"] as Storyboard;
    // Get the storboard's value to get the DoubleAnimation and manipulate it.
    var rotateImageAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyBoard.Children.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't call Foo() from the constructor, but in an onClick event. So, probably, that is not the case.

Comment: @superpuccio Updated answer

Comment: Mmh... ok, with your method I can get the storyboard, but when I obtain the storyboard var how can I have access to its DoubleAnimation child? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @superpuccio Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on llll's Answer, After you got the storyboard object, you can access the double Animation using storyboard's `Children` property.

```
var storyBoard = this.Resources["RotateImage"] as Storyboard;
var rotateImageAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyBoard.Children[0];
```

Please note accessing the animation using `children[0]` is the easiest as your storyboard is simple.